# usebox macro not expanded?

Tags: registers, xsavebox

I'm trying to store the text output of a shell command `mktemp` and reuse it later in another latex command. I'm attempting to do this using `\savebox` and `\usebox` as below. When using `\usebox` outside a command, the saved text is printed correctly. However, when used inside other commands like `\write18` and `\includegraphics`, the `\usebox` command appears to not be macroexpanded correctly:

```
\newcommand{\mktemp}[0]{
  \input{|"mktemp"}
}

\newcommand{\hrefqr}[2]{%
  \tracingall
  \newsavebox{\tmp}
  \savebox{\tmp}{\mktemp}
  %% verify that \tmp is the same file and not repeated mktemp calls
  \usebox{\tmp} \\
  \usebox{\tmp} \\
  \immediate\write18{qrencode #1 -o \usebox{\tmp}}
  \href{#1}{#2 \includegraphics[]{\usebox{\tmp}}}
}
\begin{document}
\hrefqr{www.example.com}{This is example.com}
\end{document}
```

From the logs:

```
\write->qrencode www.example.com -o \usebox {\tmp }

\usebox ->\protect \usebox  

\usebox  #1->\leavevmode \copy #1\relax 
#1<-\tmp 

\leavevmode ->\unhbox \voidb@x 
runsystem(qrencode www.example.com -o \protect \unhbox \voidb@x \copy \tmp \rel
ax )...executed safely (allowed).
```

And later:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `\usebox {\tmp }' not found.
```

from the expansion of:

```
#1<-This is example.com \includegraphics []{\usebox {\tmp }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside: you have loads of unterminated line ends in your source - you'll introduce lots of unwanted space

Comment: Store your text in a command, not a box.

Comment: Storing the marco in a command appears to re-invoke the macro multiple times, generating different temp filenames.

Comment: usebox is not expandable but you can not use a box as a filename. You already error without all your code and `\includegraphics{\mbox{example-image}}` what would you  want the box to do here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't store text in a box and retrieve it by macro expansion. When you do `\savebox{\tmp}{some text}` the argument is stored in the box register as *already typeset*.

Here's a working implementation. I create a directory, rather than a file, and in it I create `temp.png`, otherwise `\includegraphics` wouldn't be able to determine its size. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59638023.

If your version of `mktemp` supports `-suffix`, you can use it, see later for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hrefqr}{mO{}m}
 {
  % get the name of a temporary file
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { mktemp ~ -d } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  % build the QRcode
  \sys_shell_now:x { qrencode ~ #1 ~ -o ~ \l_tmpa_tl/temp.png }
  %
  \href { #1 } { #3 ~ \includegraphics[#2]{ \l_tmpa_tl/temp.png } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hrefqr{www.example.com}{This is example.com}

\hrefqr{www.example.com}[scale=0.5]{This is example.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On my system, `mktemp` doesn't support `--suffix`, but `gmktemp` (installed with Homebrew as part of `coreutils`) does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hrefqr}{mO{}m}
 {
  % get the name of a temporary file
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { gmktemp ~ --suffix ~.png } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  % build the QRcode
  \sys_shell_now:x { qrencode ~ #1 ~ -o ~ \l_tmpa_tl }
  %
  \href { #1 } { #3 ~ \includegraphics[#2]{ \l_tmpa_tl } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hrefqr{www.example.com}{This is example.com}

\hrefqr{www.example.com}[scale=0.5]{This is example.com}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't use mktemp (and generate the name in tex) but  if you do, better to use  `mktemp XXXXXX.png`  rather than append `.png` later otherwise all the checks mktemp does about not overwriting file names are  wasted

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `mktemp` wants *trailing* `X`'s. I'll give other suggestions.

Comment: oh, works here:  `$ mktemp XXX.png`  makes `nyF.png
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not on all systems, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. This was more complicated than I thought. Is there a relatively concise latex programming guide you can recommend?